# Using the same argument names in nested function causes unexpected output

Tags: r, dplyr, functional-programming, nested

Why do the first three functions (f2, f3, f4) return rows in y only for id = 1 but f5 returns all rows of y?

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

y <- tibble(id = c(1, 2))


f1 <- function(y, id) {
  y %>% filter(.data$id == {{id}})
}


f2 <- function(id) {
  f1(y, !!id)
}

f3 <- function(id) {
  f1(y, {{id}})
}

f4 <- function(x) {
  f1(y, x)
}

f5 <- function(id) {
  f1(y, id)
}


f2(1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>      id
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
f3(1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>      id
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
f4(1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>      id
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
f5(1)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>      id
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your function to show what it's evaulating, it may make a bit more sense

```
f1 <- function(y, id) {
  print(rlang::quo_squash(quo(y %>% filter(.data$id == {{id}}))))
  y %>% filter(.data$id == {{id}})
}
```

With `f5`, you get

```
y %>% filter(.data$id == id)
```

So it's returning all the rows where the column `id` is equal to the column `id` (which is every row).

You are meant to use `{{}}` when choosing columns from your data.frame. It is not useful of you are trying to specify a literal data.value.

All of your examples would have worked if you had defined `f1` as

```
f1 <- function(y, id) {
  y %>% filter(.data$id == .env$id)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see the `.env` pronoun mentioned anywhere in the Programming with dplyr vignette. Could you comment on this post about the use of `.env` vs bang-bang? [https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3286#issuecomment-355501411](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3286#issuecomment-355501411)

Comment: That thread was from 2018 and the error that was being reported doesn't seem to be an error in the current dplyr version. If you have a symbol, then you can inject that with `!!` but it will first look in the data.frame for a value. You are generally using `.env` when you don't have a symbol, but have a literal name or string and want to make sure it won't collide with any column names.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks again!